# How to use 2 filters when querying from a database, and show items from both filters id Django

Tags: django, django-models

This is my code:

```
video_object = video.objects.filter(category=category) \
    .filter(show_after_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now()) \
    .order_by("-show_after_time")
```

I want to make the filter either 'category' or another variable, say 'other_category', but it would give me items that have either 'category' or 'other_category'. How do I do that?

Comment: `.filter(category__in=[category, other_category])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
video_object = video.objects.filter(
    category__in=[category, other_category],
    show_after_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now()
).order_by('-show_after_time')
```